# MEF circular dependency

Tags: c#, mef, circular-dependency

Suppose we have two components depending on one another (indirectly, via interfaces):

```
public interface IAlice { ... }
public interface IBob { ... }

[Export(typeof(IAlice)), PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.NonShared)]
class Alice : IAlice
{
    [Import]
    private IBob Bob { get; set; }
    ...
}

// could be defined in some assembly developed by another team
[Export(typeof(IBob)), PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.NonShared)]
class Bob : IBob
{
    [Import]
    private IAlice Alice { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

This leads to composition failure: The composition failed because it did not complete within '100' iterations. This is most likely caused by a cycle in the dependency graph of a part which is marked with a non-shared creation policy.

I know I can import via Lazy declaration, but this way import will be created on demand while I need that my Alice references Bob and Bob references that same instance of Alice. I was expecting that CompositionContainer would resolve such cycles within one composition operation, but apparently it's not the case.

I can't declare parts as shared as I don't need single Alice and Bob per container. I just need that such dependency graphs are created as a single piece when it's done in one composition operation. Is there any workaround?

UPD. Added some clarification.

Comment: You mentioned in a comment to my answer that Alice and Bob could be developed by different parties. If that is the case then neither Alice nor Bob know that there is a circular dependency, hence neither can expect that they both refer to the same instance. This suggests that you lazy approach is acceptable. What am I missing?

Comment: Yes, you're right, lazy approach is acceptable. I'd prefer to allow both lazy and non-lazy imports, but seems like MEF can't handle non-lazy circular references involving non-shared parts. So we'll restrict all property imports to lazy ones. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

Why not have Alice import IBob via ctor injection and then explicitly set the Alice property of Bob (i.e. Bob should *not* use property injection for Alice)?

Comment: (I shouldn't have declared these injection properties as public, sorry — fixed). The point is that Alice and Bob are developed by different people. Alice don't know that Bob uses it, and Bob don't know it's used by Alice. We don't allow ctor injection because it can lead to the situation where this circular dependency cannot be resolved in principle, so we are stuck with property injection.

Comment: _Somebody_ has to understand the circular dependency. Make the properties public again, but remove the Import attribute. Now define `Charlie(IAlice alice, IBob bob) { alice.Bob = bob; bob.Alice = alice; }`. Give Charlie public properties for Alice and Bob and ensure that others only access Alice or Bob via these properties.

Comment: Thanks @Akash for your suggestions, but we simply can't do things that way. In our case, Alice and Bob can be plugins developed by a different parties. And we don't know any details of their implementation. *Somebody has to understand the circular dependency.* — I was hoping that this _Somebody_ could be MEF. It's only MEF that has full knowledge about all internal dependencies between components.